# Import .txt file with commas and no spaces between numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently trying to import a .txt file. I typically like the code:

```
GID = np.genfromtxt("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\Python\\myfile.txt")
q= GID[:,][:,0]
```

however I have even tried:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\Downloads\\Python\\myfile.txt', 'r') as myfile:
UV = myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
UV = UV.replace(',', ' ')
```

The problem I am currently running into is that the file I am trying to import has over 1000 rows is supposed to have two columns of numbers.  However, it separates the two columns with a comma and no space as follows:

```
1234.56,-7.89
987.65,43.21
```

If I try to import the values with the genfromtxt command it just imports everything as "nan".  If I try importing the values using the "with open" command and replacing all of the commas with spaces I loose the format of having two columns and over 1000 rows.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a comma-separated-value file (csv). Use the [python `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) or pandas `read_csv` function... Or if you want genfromtxt, you can use the delimiter parameter:

```
genfromtxt('my_file.txt', delimiter=',')
```

Comment: This worked!!  Wow, that was way too simple.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('C:\\Users\\Downloads\\Python\\myfile.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    for UV in myfile.read().replace(',', ' ').split('\n'):
        print(UV)
```

you have to split the file.read('\n') instead of replacing the new line :)